# Can I use none-pure object as state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use function instance, not pure object, as state object in react. But I'm not sure if that's ok:

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = new Domain();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So long as `typeof new Domain() == 'object'` it'll be fine.

What you have to remember (and possibly account for) is that React won't know about it if the instance updates itself.

All changes to `this.state` have to go through the `setState` interface and the `Domain` function probably doesn't know that.

```
this.state = new Domain();

// this won't cause your component to re-render
this.state.update(10);

// and this is an anti-pattern
this.setState(this.state);
```

It's very difficult to listen for changes to an object and if your domain object has instance methods which modify its state, you might find it starts to get tough to keep it in sync with your component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's ok.

There's no such thing as a pure or non-pure object in javascript (there are pure functions). There are [different notations](http://a-developer-life.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/7-ways-to-create-objects-in-javascript.html) that can be used to create a javascript object though.

One of these is the 'Function constructor' which is the one you used in `new Domain()`, and another common one is the object literal notation `{}`.

React just expects an object and he does not care which notation you used to create it.